# Safari not triggering max-width media queries on print

Tags: css, printing, safari

I got a page that is supposed to be printed by the user in different formats. Thus, I have several breakpoints in order to make it looks a tad different depending on the format (A4, A5, landscape etc.)

I noticed one problem though on Safari Browser (versions 13, 14) the breakpoint are not triggered when pressing print (`CMD + P`). The one media with `@media print` is triggered but not the width ones. I noticed that in case if you resize the window and then press `print` the breakpoint get activated.

Is there a way to force the browser to trigger those? Forcing the user to resize the window before printing is far from optimal.

I made a simple [repro](https://needy-spiders.surge.sh/test.html). The rectangle should change colour depending on the window width. If you resize window you will notice it. If you print the page the colour of the rectangle will stay.

```css
body {
            background: red;
        }

        .indicator {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            background: orange;
        }

        @media (max-width: 1200px) {
            .indicator {
                background: rebeccapurple;
            }
        }

        @media (max-width: 900px) {
            .indicator {
                background: lime;
            }
        }

        @media (max-width: 600px) {
            .indicator {
                background: teal;
            }
        }

        @media (max-width: 300px) {
            .indicator {
                background: black;
            }
        }

        @media print {
            body {
                background: green;
            }
        }
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="indicator"></div>
    <ul id="list">
    </ul>


    <script>
        const list = document.getElementById('list');

        for (let i = 0; i <= 1000; i++) {
            const li = document.createElement('li');
            li.innerText = `list element ${i}`;
            list.append(li);
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

PS: It works fine in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the below code? Hope it will work for you. We have added print `@media` with `min-width`. we add multiple media queries as per our requirement.

Please refer to this link:
https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/yj5wf7ho/

```css
body {
  background: red;
}

.indicator {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: orange;
}


@media (max-width: 900px) {
  .indicator {
      background: lime;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .indicator {
      background: teal;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 300px) {
  .indicator {
      background: black;
  }
}

@media print {
  body {
      background: green;

  }

}

@media print and (min-width: 300px) {
  .indicator {
      background: lime;
  }
}

@media print and (min-width: 600px) {
  .indicator {
      background: teal;
  }
}

@media print and (min-width: 900px) {
  .indicator {
      background: black;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="indicator"></div>
    <ul id="list">
    </ul>


    <script>
        const list = document.getElementById('list');

        for (let i = 0; i <= 1000; i++) {
            const li = document.createElement('li');
            li.innerText = `list element ${i}`;
            list.append(li);
        }
    </script>
</body>
```